# Modifying List and comparing with previous value

Tags: c#, list

I have a list whose size is not fixed. In each iteration, the number of elements in the list may get decreased, increased or remain same but with different values.

In each iteration, I receive the newer list in a setter as following:

```
public List<int> IconsColor
{
    get { return iconsColorList; }
    set
    {             
        newIconsColorList = new List<int>(value);

        if (newIconsColorList.Count == iconsColorList.Count && newIconsColorList.All(iconsColorList.Contains))
            return;

        //Else
        nIconsChanged = true;

       //??????????????????????????
       //?????????- How do I update Old list with New values
       //Something like iconsColorList = newIconsColorList;
       //but above line makes the If-condition true since both the lists are same now                                             
    }
}
```

How do I modify the elements of the previous list (`iconsColorList`) with new values (present in `newIconsColorList`)? And if the number of elements in the new list is greater than to that of the older list then, add the new element to the older list also.

Comment: This is a really bad use-case for a setter. The lack of a getter is a code smell in itself. Write-Only properties?!?

Comment: You'll get the hang of it eventually...

Comment: It's not clear why you can't use `iconsColorList = value;`. _"In each iteration, I receive the newer list in a setter as following:"_ Why you iterate a list and in each iteration you assign the complete list?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: If I use that then I think the both `iconsColorList` and `newIconsColorList` refer to the same list and therefore, the if-condition is always true (since both the lists are same).

Comment: @skm: of course, but what you want instead? Can you shown a sample?

Comment: I want to compare the current list with its previous value...if the list is same then do nothing....but if its changed then do something and finally update the list.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to merge both lists (update and add new):

```
public List<int> IconsColor
{
    set
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(iconsColorList.Count, value.Count); i++)
        {
            if (value[i] != iconsColorList[i])
            {
                iconsColorList[i] = value[i];
                nIconsChanged = true;
            }
        }

        if (value.Count > iconsColorList.Count)
        {
            // append new items to the end of the list
            iconsColorList.AddRange(value.Skip(iconsColorList.Count));
            nIconsChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Side-note: i hope the lack of a getter was just because it wasn't relevant. A property without a getter is not really useful and smells like fish. In this case it would just `return iconsColorList;`.

Comment: In addition of adding the new elements to the previous list (i.e. `iconsColorList` ), I want to update the value of elements too. For example, `previous list =0,0,0,1,0,1` and `newList=1,0,0,1,1,1,0` then, I need the updated list to be `iconsColorList=1,0,0,1,1,1,0`

Comment: @skm: so not only the content matters but also the position? Why don't you explain the requirement before?

Comment: yes, I have to check if the same index have same values or different values.

Comment: @skm IMO this whole thing is a code smell. If you add a getter, what is stopping a user going `IconsColor.Add(123)` and completely bypassing your setter logic.

Comment: JamieC is right, maybe you want to make it a method `MergeIcons` or `UpsertIcons`

Comment: @Tim: Its an HMI based from where I receive the data from HMI during each iteration and `iconsColorList` is an input from HMI.